# How to complete the drawing?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to draw the following picture:
[image]

But,  I can't finish the final details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(6,5){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,5){D}
\tkzDefPoint (3,3){E}
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](A,D)
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)  \tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDefMidPoint(D,C)  \tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzDrawArc[ultra thick](O,B)(A)
\tkzDrawArc[ultra thick](F,D)(C)
\begin{scope}
\tkzClipCircle(A,B)
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I only can do the following:

[image]

Comment: Could you edit your example so that it actually works?

Comment: The garbled code was not the fault of benedito. Someone tried to reformat the code but messed it up, and the two guys reviewing the edit accepted it without checking close enough, see the editing history.

Comment: @gernot Ah right, didn't notice the edit, thanks for the notice.

Comment: benedito, if I may, the above confusion would have been avoided if you had added proper markup for the code when you first post the question. It's quite simple, paste the code as you have it in your editor, then select it, and hit Ctrl + K on the keyboard. (Or click the button above the text field marked with `{}`.) It would be appreciated if you could do that for future questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could not compile your code - the commands with `ultra` in them, among others, couldn't be found (though this could be a problem on my end; I only have TeXLive 2016). I used the `tikz` package instead with the following code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Bounding rectangle
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,5);

% Middle fill
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) arc (180:0:3);
\clip (0,5) arc (180:360:3);
\fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (6,5);
\end{scope}

% Half circles
\draw (0,0) arc (180:0:3);
\draw (0,5) arc (180:360:3);

% Labels
\node[anchor=west] at (6,2.5) {8 cm};
\node[anchor=south] at (3,5) {10 cm};
\draw[|<->|] (1.3,3.3) to node[fill=white,midway] {?} (4.7,3.3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `fill` is called before the half circles are drawn, as otherwise the half circle parts on the boundary of the fill would be slightly narrower. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Not a problem on your end, the code in the question cannot work, because it has many errors. For example, it should most likely be `\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D)` instead of `\tkzDrawPolygonultra thick`, but there are several other incomplete instructions, and missing bracket pairs.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(6,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(6,5){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,5){D}
\tkzDefPoint (3,3){E}
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](D)
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDefMidPoint(D,C) \tkzGetPoint{F}
\begin{scope}
  \tkzClipCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawCircle[fill=gray!50, opacity=.5](F,C)
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawArc[ultra thick](O,B)(A)
\tkzDrawArc[ultra thick](F,D)(C)
\tkzInterCC(O,B)(F,D) \tkzGetPoints{I}{J}
\draw[|<->|] ($(I)+(0,1)$) to node[fill=white] {?} ($(J)+(0,1)$);
\tkzLabelSegment[right](B,C){8 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[above](C,D){10 cm}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

While you are waiting for some `tkz-euclide` support, here's a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using `luamplib`.  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u; u = 8mm;
    numeric a,b; a = 10u; b = 8u;
    path box, arc[], union, question;
    box = unitsquare xscaled a yscaled b;
    arc1 = halfcircle scaled arclength subpath(0,1) of box
                      shifted point 1/2 of box;
    arc2 = halfcircle rotated 180
                      scaled arclength subpath(2,3) of box
                      shifted point 5/2 of box;
    union = buildcycle(arc1,arc2);
    question = (point 0 of union -- point 1/2 length(union) of union) shifted (0,1/2u+1/2*abs(a-b));

    fill union withcolor 3/4[blue,white];

    draw arc1; draw arc2;
    draw box withpen pencircle scaled 1;

    draw (up--down) scaled 2 shifted point 0 of question;
    draw (up--down) scaled 2 shifted point 1 of question;
    drawdblarrow question;

    label.top(decimal round(arclength(subpath(2,3) of box)/u) & " cm", point 5/2 of box);
    label.rt (decimal round(arclength(subpath(1,2) of box)/u) & " cm", point 3/2 of box);

    picture q; 
    q = thelabel("?", point 1/2 of question);
    unfill bbox q;
    draw q;

    % uncomment this to show the answer instead of the ?
    % picture a; 
    % a = thelabel(decimal round(arclength(question)/u) & " cm", point 1/2 of question);
    % unfill bbox a;
    % draw a;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```